# Why does the math equation always result in a 0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, properties

I am currently trying to practice using Xamarin in Visual Studio for the first time and I decided to try to make a calculator app. I have tried different ways to make this app and just found out that using properties could make it run more effectively. But, after trying to implement a certain format from another source, somehow the results are always zero.

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CalculatorApp.Calculator2">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="display" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="End"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="End"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="buttonYellow" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FF9F2A"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="buttonGrey" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#AAAAAA"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#424242"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="buttonDarker" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#333333"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <!--Content Starts here-->

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <!--Row and Column Definitions-->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--First Row-->
            <Label x:Name="displayLbl" Text="{Binding LblText}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource display}"/>

            <!--AC and Divide-->
            <Button Text="AC" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonGrey}" Clicked="ClearButton"/>
            <Button Text="÷" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonYellow}" Clicked="DivideButton"/>

            <!--Third Row-->
            <Button Text="7" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="8" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="×" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonYellow}" Clicked="MultiplyButton"/>

            <!--Fourth Row-->
            <Button Text="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="6" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="-" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonYellow}" Clicked="MinusButton"/>

            <!--Fifth Row-->
            <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="+" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonYellow}" Clicked="PlusButton"/>

            <!--Sixth Row-->
            <Button Text="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonDarker}" Clicked="CalculatorButtons"/>
            <Button Text="=" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource buttonYellow}" Clicked="EqualButton"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CalculatorApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Calculator2 : ContentPage
    {
        private double _Number = 0;
        public double Number
        {
            get
            {
                return _Number;
            }
            set
            {
                _Number = value;
                displayLbl.Text = _Number.ToString();
            }
        }

        private double _Result;
        public double Result
        {
            get
            {
                return _Result;
            }

            set
            {
                _Result = value;
                displayLbl.Text = _Result.ToString();
            }
        }

        public Calculator2 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void CalculatorButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            displayLbl.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
        }


        #region Operation Buttons
        private void PlusButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result += Number;
            Number = 0.0;
        }

        private void MinusButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result -= Number;
            Number = 0.0;
        }

        private void MultiplyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result *= Number;
            Number = 0.0;
        }

        private void DivideButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result /= Number;
            Number = 0.0;
        }

        private void EqualButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result = Number;
        }

        private void ClearButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearCommand();
        }
        #endregion

        public void ClearCommand() {
            displayLbl.Text = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What inputs are you using to test?  Have you used the debugger to step through your code and verify your logic?

Comment: @Jason I tried using breakpoints to pinpoint which area might be the error

Comment: your +-/* methods all set Number = 0.0, and your EqualButton sets Result = Number.

Comment: @Jason what I'm initially trying to do is set the number that was first entered before pressing the operation buttons into a variable and then after a new number is entered, pressing another operation button is gonna initiate the math operations

Answer (score 0):

1.) Your clear command should also reset the Result to 0, because by looking at this code, regardless of how many times you clear, it looks like the Result will still accumulate.

2.) `Number` is always zero because you're not setting it anywhere (it's not bound to any of the buttons) besides resetting it back to 0 after every operator function call. Based on your current design, something you could do inside of your `CalculatorButtons` function, is keep appending the strings of digits based on the `((Button)sender).Text` and once a +-* function is called, convert that to a digit and perform your calculation.

Whether or not this approach is the most efficient approach (it's not) is a different question altogether.